# Excel 2010 - Need to sum dynamic range based on trailing 3 months

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, array

I am trying to sum a dynamic range for a list of entries 3 months before and 3 months after a specific month.  I think I need to use an array to get this, but I'm not able to find what I need to do.

Here's what I have in a Matrix format currently:

```
ROW  |  COLUMN A  |  COLUMN B  |  COLUMN C  |  COLUMN D  |  COLUMN E
---  |  ------------------------------------------------------------
1    |  Username  |  StartMo   |  January   |  February  |  March
     |  ____________________________________________________________
2    |  User 1    |  March     |  1,000     |  1,500     |  1,000
3    |  User 2    |  April     |  2,000     |  1,000     |  1,500
4    |  User 3    |  April     |  1,000     |  1,750     |  1,000
```

- Users 1-10 in column A
- Start Month in column B
- Monthly data over past year in columns C-M
- Headers stating the month of the data across Row 1

What I need to do is Sum if Column A has the User I want, but only if Row 1 is within 3 months of the Start Month.

Thoughts?  I'd love to post a picture of the data but since I am new it won't let me.

Comment: Can you _type_ some example data into the question? Also, do you mean columns C-N? C-M is only 11 columns (not a full year).

Comment: Does that work better, @G-Man ?

Comment: So, for example, for User 1 (Row 2), you would want to sum C2:G2 (January-June), and for User 2 (Row 3) you would want to sum C3:H3 (January-July)?

Comment: Yes Sir, dynamically by the Start Month

Comment: Still looking for help on this issue if anyone's available.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each row, you want to sum a range that is a subset of that row,
determined by the “Start Month” in Column B. 
Let’s begin by taking your textual description of the range and expressing it formulaically. 
To do this, we’ll need to convert the month names to numbers, 1 through 12. 
I don’t know of a way to do that directly, but it’s easy to extract the month number from a *date*,
and we can turn a month name into a date by appending a number (day of the month). 
For example,

- if `B2` is `March`, then
- `B2 & "1"` is `March1`, and
- `MONTH(B2 & "1")` is `3`.
- If this doesn’t work in your version of Excel, try `MONTH(DATEVALUE(B2 & "1"))`.

OK, the question asks to sum months *month number*−3 through *month number*+3. 
For example, for User 2 (Row 3), where `B3` is “April” (i.e., 4),
we want the sum of January (1) through July (7), since 4−3=1 and 4+3=7. 
But there’s a catch: not all of the required seven months are guaranteed to be present on the sheet. 
For User 1 (Row 2), `B2` is “March”, so we want December (of the prior year) through June. 
Data for the prior and following year aren’t available,
so we truncate our range to January through June. 
We do this by forcing the start month to be no less than 1 and the end month to be no more than 12.

If we do this with one monolithic formula, it will be practically unreadable. 
It’s much clearer to use “helper columns” to store intermediate values. 
So, set

- `P2` – month number corresponding to `B2`:
  `=MONTH(B2 & "1")`
- `Q2` – start month of range:
  `=MAX(P2-3, 1)`
- `R2` – end month of range:
  `=MIN(P2+3, 12)`

Highlighting the cells that we have selected is a neat trick,
and can help us verify that we’re doing what we want to be doing. 
Setting a conditional format with a formula of

```
=AND((COLUMN())-2>=$Q2, (COLUMN()-2)<=$R2)
```

on our data matrix, we get this:

[image: partial answer]
<sup>(The image is a link to a larger copy of itself.)</sup>

A good tool for generating dynamic ranges in Excel is the [`OFFSET`](http://support.office.microsoft.com/client/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) function:

```
OFFSET(reference, rows, cols, [height], [width])
```

which identifies a rectangular region of cells (possibly a single cell;
i.e., a 1×1 rectangle; possibly larger) by its position relative to some other cell. 
For example, `OFFSET(B2, 0, 1, , 6)` identifies the range `C2:H2`, because

- From cell `B2`, going down 0 rows and right 1 column gets you to `C2`,
- The height defaults to 1, so the range is entirely in row 2, and
- The width is 6: `C2`, `D2`, `E2`, `F2`, `G2`, and `H2`, or `C2:H2` for short, is six columns.

Well, the width of the range is simply the end column number minus the start column number plus 1. 
So the result you want is simply

```
=SUM(OFFSET(B2, 0, Q2, , R2-Q2+1))
```

And we can put that into Column `O`:

[image: full answer]

Here is the above in text form, so you can copy and paste it:

<sub>`Username   StartMo   January     February    March       April       May         June        July        August      September   October     November    December   The Answer
Andy       March     102         202         402         1002        2002        4002        10002       20002       40002       100002      200002      400002      =SUM(OFFSET(B2,0,Q2,,R2-Q2+1))   =MONTH(B2&"1")   =MAX(P2-3,1)   =MIN(P2+3,12)
Bob        April     103         203         403         1003        2003        4003        10003       20003       40003       100003      200003      400003      =SUM(OFFSET(B3,0,Q3,,R3-Q3+1))   =MONTH(B3&"1")   =MAX(P3-3,1)   =MIN(P3+3,12)
Charlie    April     104         204         404         1004        2004        4004        10004       20004       40004       100004      200004      400004      =SUM(OFFSET(B4,0,Q4,,R4-Q4+1))   =MONTH(B4&"1")   =MAX(P4-3,1)   =MIN(P4+3,12)`</sub>

You may need to paste it into Word as text, and then copy that and paste it into Excel.